# (Not text to columns) - break 1 colums into many with delimiter

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet with 1 column and many lines. I have a delimiter (;) at the position where I want to split the column to a new column, to arrange the data. Each colum will contain between 5 to 10 rows (its random) with informations like name, adress, etc

Basically I want to transform my sheet from the yellow part (A) to what you see in black.
I tried to play with the Pivot or the Text to columns, but without success :-(

Thank you for your help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If open to VBA solution

---

```
Sub Try()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, r As Long, c As Long, i As Long

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
r = 1
c = 3

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To lr
        If ws.Range("A" & i) = ";" Then
            c = c + 1
            r = 1
        Else
            ws.Cells(r, c).Value = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

[image]

Comment: Many thanks to you it's working properly on my excel

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun using dynamic arrays in Microsoft365:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,$A1:$A17)&"</s></t>","//s[count(preceding::*[.=';'])="&COLUMN(A1)-1&"][.!=';']")
```

Drag to the right...

- `"<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,$A1:$A17)&"</s></t>"` - Create a valid xml-string concatenating all values from the appropriate range in column A.
- `//s` - Return those nodes where:

  - `count(preceding::*[.=';'])="&COLUMN(A1)-1&"]` - The count of preceding nodes that are equal to ";" is based on the `COLUMN(A1)-1` part and;
  - `[.!=';']` - Nodes themselves are not equal to ";".

Comment: `FILTERXML` is a upvote from me every time. Never been able to get it to work on my own without reading someone else's solution as I try. Amazing

Comment: @urdearboy. Thanks. I hope it's clear to you how to obtain nodes in this situation? Either way, I'm not sure how feasible this solution is with an obvious restriction to how many characters `TEXTJOIN()` can handle. Like I mentioned, the answer is there out of curiousity =)

Comment: It's always so clear until I try to use it from memory later haha